# Using Homebrew how do I remove some specific versions but not all old versions

Tags: macos, homebrew

Using Homebrew's brew command, I would like to remove some specific versions of a formula and keep others.

I know that I can use brew cleanup to remove **all** old versions but this isn't exactly what I want. Cleanup will remove all the old versions, but I wish to keep one of them.

To be specific, I have the following versions of a package installed:
* 2.10.3
* 2.10.4
* 2.11.0
* 2.11.1

I would like to keep the current version, right now that's 2.11.1 and also keep version 2.10.4. I would like to remove the other versions, 2.11.0 and 2.10.3.

Comment: btw, I did see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula?rq=1 which seems somewhat related but I failed to join the dots on solving my specific situation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just `rm -rf` them from the Cellar.

Comment: Not really. I also had to `brew prune` and `brew link <package_name>` to have executables available.

Comment: @ciastek: You have to do  that if you're removing the currently active version, in which case it's better to do `brew rm <package> && brew ln <package>`.

Comment: @mipadi And how do I remove from the `Cellar` ?

Comment: I tried this, and now I'm getting this error `Error: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0 is not a directory`. I pinned python 3.6.5_1 and did `brew switch python 3.6.5_1`, then removed the 3.7.0 directory. Any way to remove 3.7.0 and not break brew?

Answer (score 37):

To remove all old versions:

```
brew cleanup
```

To remove old version of X package:

```
brew cleanup X
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't answer the question asked. Cleanup will remove all the old versions, but I wish to keep one of the old versions.

Comment: Yep… this case is a bit more complicate… you want to keep one of the old versions of some package. So the mipadi’s answer best applies.